# passport.authenticate successRedirect condition

Tags: express, passport.js, passport-local

In my app.js I have:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/admin/users',
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}), function (req, res) {
});
```

My user object looks like this:

```
{ _id: 586afad4a4ff884d28b6ca97,
  firstName: 'Joseph',
  ...
  isAdmin: false }
```

What I want to do is:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: {
    if(req.body.user.isAdmin === true) {
      res.redirect('/admin/users')
    }
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  },
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}), function (req, res) {
});
```

but it doesn't seem that I can. What will be the easiest example of checking if the user is an admin or doing the login post using passport.authenticate

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. The optional object in passport.authenticate confused me. So what I did was:

```
router.post(
  '/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  }), (req, res) => {
    if (req.user.isAdmin === true) {
      res.redirect('/admin/gifts?filter=review');
    }
    if (req.user.isAdmin === false) {
      res.redirect('/dashboard/received');
    }
  });
```